# is there a thing which delete downloaded files from /tmp/ in Fedora/Firefox?

Tags: filesystems, fedora

This may seem like a insane question, but is there a thing in Fedora 16/17 which delete .jpg images from /tmp/ ?

I had 4GB of pictures stored in /tmp/download which are all gone now. The folder structure is still there, but all the folders are empty.

And the insane thing is that this is the second time this happens to me. Both times from /tmp/download.

My filesystem seems to be fine(Running raid-1) and there are no other missing files at all.

So is it me who deleted the files and forgot, or is it Fedora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a cleanup job in /etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch that will nuke files that haven't been accessed in a while (30 days by default).

`man 8 tmpwatch` might yield some more insight

Comment: Moreover, it's generally a bad habit to store valuable stuff under /tmp. I've seen systems set up with /tmp backed by tmpfs (e.g. ephemeral, swap-backed, nothing survives reboot...)

Comment: That is it i guess.

Comment: And just in case anyone cares. Fedora 18 will also clear /tmp/ on reboot, so I better get out of my habit of using /tmp for anything.

Answer (score 0):

From Fedora 18 on, `/tmp` is mounted on `tmpfs` (i.e. RAM) by default, and thus erased on power off.

This behaviour can be disabled by issuing `systemctl mask tmp.mount` and reboot (and reenabled by issuing `systemctl unmask tmp.mount` and reboot), and then `/tmp` will be mounted on the `/` filesystem and can be controlled by `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` settings.

See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/tmp-on-tmpfs and `man tmpfiles.d` for more details on each case.